# RabbitMQ keeps closing connection

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using rabbitpy python library to interact with RabbitMQ. I designed a communication class that have a publisher method and a consumer method. This communication class' instances run in separate threads.

If I begin frequent requests, RabbitMQ closes connection. Here is the error log:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Apr-2014::14:12:52 ===
AMQP connection <0.13197.22> (running), channel 1 - error:
{amqp_error,unexpected_frame,
            "expected content header for class 60, got non content header frame instead",
            'basic.publish'}

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Apr-2014::14:12:52 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.13197.22> (127.0.0.1:52234 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 4-Apr-2014::14:12:52 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.13263.22> (127.0.0.1:52237 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
```

rabbitpy is a thread safe library (it says so).

Why am I having such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem is multi threading. May be it's a bug in `rabbitpy`.
The solution is to either

- Avoid publishing on the same channel within connection from multiple threads
- Synchronize publishing in your own code

Check out [this discussion](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2013-September/030535.html)

Comment: I knew the discussion before, but since rabbitpy library is declared as thread safe, I thought this issue can not be related with multi threading. Regarding your comment, I used threading.RLock() explained [here](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) right before message.publish(). It seems it's working for now. We'll see actual results in the next 1-2 days. I'll notify.

Comment: Interesting, rabbitpy uses Queue.Queue to deal with frames across thread. You shouldn't need to lock at that point, but I'll take a look and see.

It would be helpful to see any sample code that can cause this to happen reliably.